# "10 $digest() iterations reached" when ng-repeat a list from a directive's controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that will display a given data. Displaying the data involves a simple parsing that I put in the directive's controller functions. When running this, I got the infamous `10 $digest() iteration reached` error but can't understand why.

I've isolated everything into this very simple plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/D8X9AmfDPdbvQDr4ENBR?p=preview

Can someone tell:

- Why does it only fail when I use ng-repeat to iterate the getList() function results but not when I just print it?
- Why does it only fail when I return an Array from getList() but not when I return an Object?
- Why does it only fail when the list is returned from getList() but the same list, just static in the controller, works?

I must say I'm confused here...

Answer (score 1):

Doing `return [...];` creates a *new* array every time. Then `ng-repeat` thinks the watched expression has changed and trigges another digest cycle... which calls `getList()` again, returning a new array, triggering and so on.

I thought using `track by` in the `ng-repeat` expression would help, but it doesn't. It seems that `track by` can relate newer version of objects *inside* the array, but not changes to the array itself.

The only way is to make sure you **return the same array reference every time**. E.g.:

```
controller: function($scope) {
    var list = [];

    $scope.getList = function() {
        return list;
    };

    $scope.fetchList = function() {
        // You would need a way to fill the list. Can of course be done in
        // the initializer, i.e. `var list = [{x:1, y:2}]`, but this is a trivial
        // case; you probably want to call a service and fill the list.
        ...
    };

    $scope.removeFromList = function(item) {
        // also remember *not* to change the reference when manipulating the list,
        // e.g. removing items: do it in place with `splice()`, `push()` etc
        var index = list.indexOf(item);
        if( index >= 0 ) {
            list.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
}
```

Using `track by` has its own merits anyway, so consider it, but it is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: Thanks! that explains things.  What should I do if `list` is a scope variable in the directive, coming from the parent controller and it takes time to load? According to what you've said, I want to do all the parsing when $scope.list gets a new value and store it in the directive's controller but it seems that I'm not getting notified when the parent changes the list. It does reflect in the template but link() isn't called again.

Comment: From what you say, you should probably add a watch - could also be a `watchCollection`. But this is too abstract, it's better to provide some code.